# KCL 2.x is polling Kinesis stream at slower rate than configured

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

I have a KCL application where I am not setting any value for `idleTimeBetweenReadsInMillis` of `PollingConfig` class. So, it should be using default value set i.e. 1000ms (1sec).
This should poll 60 times in a minute, however when I check the count `GetRecords.Records` metric for a given stream, I see only 40 `GetRecords` call made in a minute. Why is this happening and how can this be fixed?